# In java, the is the stream type when using the audioManager. (like STREAM_MUSIC) what does the stream type mean?

Tags: java, android-studio, stream, audio-streaming, android-audiomanager

I have no idea what the stream type in java music manager is, I looked all over the internet but found no answer... what does it mean and what other types of stream are there?

Answer (score 0):

You can find detail for STREAM_MUSIC and other Audio attributes from below link.
STREAM_ are now deprecated but Compatibility type are added for same.

https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes

Based on Compatibility you can find detail for that attributes
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioAttributes.html#USAGE_MEDIA